# Value of Radio Button display differently on Ionic Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, button, ionic2

I'm working with ionic and I wanted to display the data with value on the radio button. I'm having trouble with getting the value and setting it to the correct one.

index.html

```
    <td>
      <label>{{learningtest.Questions}}</label>
    </td>
    <td *ngFor="let button of learningtest.Buttons">
      <input type="radio" 
      ng-model="learningtest.selectedAnswer" 
      name="button{{idx}}" 
      value="{{learningtest.Buttons[idx]}}"
      >button{{idx}}           
      {{learningtest.Buttons[idx] | json}}
    </td>
   <td>
      <p>{{learningtest.selectedAnswer}}</p>
   </td>
  </tr>
```

The typescript:

```
learningtests = [{
    Questions: "You have a personal or private interest or hobby that you like to do alone.",
    selectedAnswer: "",

    Buttons: [{
        Button: "0"
      },
      {
        Button: "1"
      },
      {
        Button: "2"
      }
    ]


  },



  {
    Questions: "You keep a journal or personal diary to record your thoughts.",
    selectedAnswer: "",

    Buttons: [{
        Button: "0"
      },
      {
        Button: "1"
      },
      {
        Button: "2"
      }
    ]

  },
  {
    Questions: "You use rhythm or rhyme to remember things, eg phone numbers, passwords, other little sayings.",
    selectedAnswer: "",

    Buttons: [{
        Button: "0"
      },
      {
        Button: "1"
      },
      {
        Button: "2"
      }
    ]
  },

  {
    Questions: "You like logic games and brainteasers. You like chess and other strategy games.",
    selectedAnswer: "",

    Buttons: [{
        Button: "0"
      },
      {
        Button: "1"
      },
      {
        Button: "2"
      }
    ]
  },

  //5
  {
    Questions: "You are a tinkerer. You like pulling things apart, and they usually go back together OK. You can easily follow instructions represented in diagrams.",
    selectedAnswer: "",

    Buttons: [{
        Button: "0"
      },
      {
        Button: "1"
      },
      {
        Button: "2"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

The output:

[image]

Comment: Please use the correct tags (angular/angularjs, which is it?) Seems like angular (v. 2+), but using syntax belonging to angularjs, at least I see use of `ng-model` ;)

Comment: Use `[value]=".."` or `ngValue=".."` instead

Comment: Adding to @devqon , It should also use `[(ngModel)]` instead of `ng-model`

Comment: thanks. But still did not display the value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be

```
<td *ngFor="let learn of learningtest">
   <table>
      <tr>
         <td *ngFor="let btn of learn.Buttons">
            <input type="radio" [(ngModel)]="learn.selectedAnswer"
               name="button{{idx}}" 
               [value]="btn">
            button{{idx}}           
            {{btn | json}}
         </td>
      </tr>
   </table>
</td>
```

use **`[(ngModel)]`** also use nested `ngFor`

**[DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/V5c5YxMuMGJPAFpNW4Di?p=preview)**

Comment: check the demo attached

Comment: it's a dropdown list ?

Comment: Thanks Mate! Really helpful hehe